# Programmatic authentication of a client

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I'm using Keycloak OIDC to secure my REST application running on Quarkus (lets name it repository). I have another app that has to be protected with mutual TLS (lets call it api-service). Api-service is a client of repository. How to authorize api-service call to repository when I have prinicipal obtained from mTLS? I was playing a little bit with Keycloak mTLS but it doesn't seem to be an option because it will require changes to clients of api-service and it's not possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need may be implementing interceptor with `ContainerRequestFilter`

Override the filter method so that it checks the principal information sent with each request for api-service call. Filtering out unauthorized access like:

```
@Override
public void filter( ContainerRequestContext context ) {
    // Check if any authentication is provided for obtained principal
    // Abort with unauthorized response if not
    context.abortWith( Response.status( Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED ).build() );
}
```